# Using WPF to display XML

Tags: wpf, xml, binding

I have a small project that I think WPF would be perfect for, I don't however have that much time so I am looking for feasibility information and pointers. I am trying to display a large number of items from an XML document and from what I have read so far I believe it would be possible to:

Use the XML document as a dataSource.

Load each item from the XML into an object, which is then added to a collection. (Is it possible to bind the XML straight to the collection?)

Using the collection bind it to a view.

Each object in the view is displayed in a similar fashion to that of an HTML table. (Use a custom control in stackPanel vertically?)

There may be thousands of objects within the collection so need to be be able to display only 50/page with the ability to sort and search. (Using collectionView?)

I have seen similar scenarios and examples on the web but most are watered down, I don't want to start this and then hit a brick wall when I could create a web based solution.

If anyone could tell me if it's possible, point me in the right direction or highlight any potential problem areas it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this sample xml file:

```
<Employees>
  <Employee ID="101">
    <Name>Ram</Name>
    <Salary>5000</Salary>
  </Employee>
  <Employee ID="102">
    <Name>Siva</Name>
    <Salary>7000</Salary>
  ...
</Employee>
```

You can load the data from an xml file like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(yourFilePath);
```

Then you can query it like this:

```
var filterQuery = from i in doc.Descendants("someNode")
                  where (float)i.Element("Salary") >= 6000.00
                  orderby (string)i.Element("Name")
                  select (string)i.Element("Name");
```

Create an ObservableCollection out of it

```
var filteredList = new ObservableCollection(filterQuery);
```

Bind this to your ListView or other Collection in xaml.

You can implement sorting and searching logics on the `doc` and re-populate your ObservableCollection anytime and the changes would be automatically reflected in the ListView.